Pass a reference to a sensor or create the sensor object in the class
Note to SO.  If I ask this question to AI I get a very similar output as the accepted reply.  Without out all the questions about how I asked the question.  Just sayin.
I am using this class for sensors.  Each sensor has multiple capabilities (Temp and Humidity....).  I need to access some of the properties of the sensor beyond the output values.
class Sensor {
public:
    int id;
    int sensorTypeVal;
    const char* name; 
    SensorReading reading; 

    // Constructor to initialize Sensor with id, type, and name
    Sensor(int id, int type, const char* name)
        : id(id), sensorTypeVal(type), name(name) {} // Initialize reading with default constructor

    // Constructor to initialize Sensor with id, type, name, and a SensorReading
    Sensor(int id, int type, const char* name, const SensorReading& reading)
        : id(id), sensorTypeVal(type), name(name), reading(reading) {}

    // Method to update the sensor reading
    void updateReading(const SensorReading& newReading) {
        reading = newReading;
    }
};

Fairly new to C++ so wondering what the normal approach is here.  I found this Why should I use a pointer rather than the object itself?
Which seems a level up from my question.  I don't want to get into the sensor "wrapper" pattern and start duplicating properties across layers.  Is it recommended to pass a ref to the sensor in on init, or move the sensor object inside the class and abstract it away?
Or is there another way to compose it?

Consider also, different sensors inheriting from the common Sensor class.

you shouldnt pass the name by const char*, thats for sure. Use std::string for strings

I don't get this. You talk about 'the class' and passing a reference to a sensor object 'on init' or to 'move the sensor object into the class'. But the class you show is called Sensor. Are you talking about moving a Sensor object into the Sensor class? That makes no sense.

Sensor is a class, there is a generally a library where the "sensor" is created such as
Adafruit_AHTX0 aht;
I can also create a ref  like so Adafruit_AHTX0& raht = aht; Is it better to create the 'sensor' and the reference outside the class in the main program, or have private methods in the class that init the Adafruit_AHTX0 aht;

What you are asking depends on details you are not sharing.  All the approaches you describe would work, I think you realize.  And there would be differences.  And you are asking which differences best suit your specific needs.  But we don't know what your needs are.  Are you asking when a variable should be a reference?  Are you asking when a library should expose which objects it manages?


Sensor is a class, there is a generally a library where the "sensor"
is created such as Adafruit_AHTX0 aht; I can also create a ref like so
Adafruit_AHTX0& raht = aht; Is it better to create the 'sensor' and
the reference outside the class in the main program, or have private
methods in the class that init the Adafruit_AHTX0 aht;

When you  Adafruit_AHTX0 aht; you create an instance of the class  Adafruit_AHTX0 ie you allocate the memory for the class, and the default constructor is being called. The latter creates reference (alias) to the instance of the class Adafruit_AHTX0.
The place whe you create the instance of the class depends of the program needs but if has quite importan repercusions:

Memory used and constructor call timing




Scope
Memory Segment
Lifetime
Constructor Call
Access




Global
Global/Static segment
Entire program duration
Before main() starts
Accessible across the program (if not static).


Local (Stack)
Stack memory
Within the enclosing block
When the block or function is entered
Limited to its function/block.


Dynamic (Heap)
Heap memory
Until explicitly deallocated
When new is called
Accessible via pointers.


Static (Local)
Global/Static segment
Persistent across the program (initialized only once)
First time the block is executed
Limited to its function/block.


Static (Global)
Global/Static segment
Entire program duration
Before main() starts
Accessible across the program.



Small embedded targets have their specific needs - nor necessary following the best practices for "normal" big computers. It is very broad topic far beyond a simple SO answer.

Thanks for this, exactly what I was looking for.
